# Logstash unable to send messages to Graylog

Tags: logstash, graylog

I am unable to post messages to my graylog server. I have turned on my debug in logstash, I can see messages going out but I never recieve them in my graylog server. I have tested connectivity between the two servers using `nc` and it works.

```
echo -e '{"version": "1.1","host":"example.org","short_message":"Short message","full_message":"Backtrace here\n\nmore stuff","level":1,"_user_id":9001,"_some_info":"foo","_some_env_var":"bar"}\0' | nc -w 1 111.222.333.444 12201
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Logstash does not support GELF with TCP. Try it with a UDP/GELF input, it should work.